# Getting the background color of a WKInterfaceGroup programmatically (WatchKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

How can you programmatically get the background color of a WKInterfaceGroup object?

You can [set the value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceGroup_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceGroup/setBackgroundColor:) using

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(nullable UIColor *)color;
```

but can you also get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a way to GET the background Color.

I've never used any WatchKit stuff before, but after looking at the WKInterfaceGroup class and reading up on it a little bit, here is my understanding of how WatchKit appears to work.

It looks like Apple wants communication (at least in the scope of the files I've looked at) to be one way. That is, they don't want you to retrieve things like that from the watch to the app level. They want you to tell the watch what to do, and the watch only receives these things (like color, inset, corner radius, etc.)

This is the conclusion I have come to (not sure if I'm right). Now, if you NEED to get the background color from the WKInterfaceGroup, then you can keep trying to find a solution. I do not know if it is possible. What I would recommend is trying to find an alternate solution to needing this property from WKInterfaceGroup.

Answer (score 2):

You can set values on an interface object, but you *can't* get the current values of its attributes.

This answer can be found in the [`WKInterfaceObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceObject_class/index.html) superclass documentation:

> Communication between an interface object in your extension and the corresponding interface element in your Watch app is one way. You can set the values of an interface object, but you cannot get the current values. If you want to know the current value of an attribute, you must save the value yourself.

Here is an example showing how to maintain your own value for the group color:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myGroup: WKInterfaceGroup!
var myGroupBackgroundColor: UIColor?

// Set the group's color, also save the color for future reference
myGroupBackgroundColor = UIColor.blue()
myGroup.setBackgroundColor(myGroupBackgroundColor)
```

You can then get the group's current color using your `myGroupBackgroundColor` property.